# Convert Imagemagick command to php imagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I need to convert the ImageMagick Command to PHP Imagick. I have tried a few combinations but nothing worked as expected. The command creates a line with pointy edges and gradient at the edges
 The command is:

```
convert -size 300x1 xc:red \
\( -size 1x300 gradient: -rotate 90 -solarize 50% -level 0x50% -white-threshold 50% +write grad.png \) \
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite red_grad.png`
```

thanks to @fmw42 for this command

I have tried the following code:

```
$line = new Imagick();
$line->newPseudoImage(300,1,'xc:red');
$shadow = new Imagick();
$shadow->newPseudoImage(1, 300, 'gradient:red-white');
$shadow->rotateImage('transparent', 90);
$shadow->solarizeImage(50);
$shadow->levelImage(0,50,50);
$shadow->whiteThresholdImage('white');
$shadow->setImageCompose(0);
$shadow->writeImage('grad.png');
$shadow->compositeImage($line, Imagick::COMPOSITE_MATHEMATICS, 0, 0);
```

Please point out where am I going wrong

Comment: Why are you creating a red-white gradient? In my code it is black and white. I then solarize. Use levelImage (0, 1.0, 65535/2). Gamma value should be 1.  Imagick does not use percent, but values in the range 0 to 65535 (quantum range) for black point and white point. The solarized gradient goes into the alpha channel of the red line using composite of copy_opacity, not mathematics. I do not know Imagick well enough, but why do you need two sets of new Imagick. I think you only need one.

Comment: Note also that solarize value should be 50*quantumrange/100 as it needs to be in the range of 0 to 65535 for Q16 ImageMagick. Also the white threshold is not a color, but a value in the same range. So for my 50% it would be 50*quantumrange/100. Please read the Imagick documentation more carefully and look at the notes/comments at the bottom of each page and refer to the links on them about arguments.

Comment: Correction, you need two new Imagick commands.

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: with a few tweaks, your answer worked. Thanks

Comment: Please show the corrected code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a few tweaks, @fmw42 answer worked for me. The correct solution is given below

```
$redline = new Imagick();
$redline->newPseudoImage(1100,3,'xc:'.$chipColourPixel->getColorAsString());
$grad = new Imagick();
$grad->newPseudoImage(3, 900, 'gradient:black-white');
$grad->rotateImage('white', 90);
$grad->solarizeImage((int)ceil(50*Imagick::QUANTUM_RANGE/100));
$grad->levelImage(0,1,50*Imagick::QUANTUM_RANGE/100);
$redline->compositeImage($grad, Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0, 0);
$redline->writeImage("redline.png");
```

Answer (score 2):

My best guess at translation would be the following. However, this is untested and I do not know Imagick well.

```
$redline = new Imagick();
$redline->newPseudoImage(300,1,'xc:red');
$grad = new Imagick();
$grad->newPseudoImage(1, 300, 'gradient:black-white');
$grad->rotateImage('white', 90);
$grad->solarizeImage(50*Imagick::getQuantumRange/100);
$grad->levelImage(0,1,50*Imagick::getQuantumRange/100);
$grad->whiteThresholdImage(50*Imagick::getQuantumRange/100);
$redline->compositeImage($grad, Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0, 0);
$redline->writeImage("redline.png");
```